# How to get the page to update once the contents of a div has changed

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the text in a div, but am not having very much luck. From scrounging around I have come up with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function UpdateDiv(fieldname, text) {
        document.getElementById(fieldname).innerHTML = "<strong>" + text + "</strong>"
    }

    function UpdateElapsed() {
        UpdateDiv("Key", "You Clicked Update");
    }
</script>

<div id="Key">Hi there</div>
<form name="DemoForm" action="">
    <button onclick="UpdateElapsed()">Update</button>
</form>
```

however after I click the update the words "Hi there" remain there.. If I click update a bunch of times every once in a while, it will say "You Clicked update". I realize this is probably very simple, but I'm new and stuck. Please be kind :)

Comment: Just some feedback regarding style etc. 
I think it's more common to not have capitals at the start of functions as they imply to be classes. Also don't use the inline onclick on buttons but rather add the eventhandler through Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solutions:
1. You can remove the form, and the code will work fine.

```
 function UpdateDiv(fieldname, text) {
     document.getElementById(fieldname).innerHTML = "<strong>" + text + "</strong>";
 }

 function UpdateElapsed() {
     UpdateDiv("Key", "You Clicked Update");
 }

<div id="Key">Hi there</div>
<button onclick="UpdateElapsed()">Update</button>
```

2. Add `return false` in the `UpdateElapsed` function

```
 function UpdateDiv(fieldname, text) {
     document.getElementById(fieldname).innerHTML = "<strong>" + text + "</strong>";
 }

 function UpdateElapsed() {
     UpdateDiv("Key", "You Clicked Update");
     return false;
 }
<div id="Key">Hi there</div>
<form name="DemoForm" method="get">
    <button onclick="return UpdateElapsed()">Update</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function UpdateDiv(fieldname, text) {
        document.getElementById(fieldname).innerHTML = "<strong>" + text + "</strong>"
    }

    function UpdateElapsed() {
        UpdateDiv("Key", "You Clicked Update");
    }
</script>

<div id="Key">Hi there</div>
    <button onclick="UpdateElapsed()">Update</button>
```

Comment: I noticed that you removed the outer form tag, but it still does not seem to work for me. Now I can see the page flash, and the other text for a brief second, but then it resets back to 'hi there'

Comment: works fine for me after remove form tag and it wont refresh page.

Answer (score 1):

Its working fine for me.. Could you show your entire code?  Sorry this was not a comment, you need 50 rep to comment so i had to put it as an answer.

Comment: That is all the code.. Except for the body and the html tags (I have the script inside the <head>, but for some reason the code tags did not like those tags so I deleted them.

Comment: Ah it lets me comment on my own post :) Well that bizzare. What browser are you using? Also donnywals post about removing the form from the code may work, did you remove the <form name="DemoForm" action=""> as well as the </form>?

Answer (score 0):

If you give the button an id and add the eventlistener through javascript it works.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q9Wrv/)

CODE:

html:

```
<div id="Key">Hi there</div>
<button id="my_btn">Update</button>
```

javascript:

```
function UpdateDiv(fieldname, text) {
    document.getElementById(fieldname).innerHTML = "<strong>" + text + "</strong>"
}

function UpdateElapsed() {
    UpdateDiv("Key", "You Clicked Update");
}

document.getElementById('my_btn').addEventListener('click', UpdateElapsed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function UpdateDiv(fieldname, text) {
    document.getElementById(fieldname).innerHTML = "<strong>" + text + "</strong>"
}

function UpdateElapsed() {
    UpdateDiv("Key", "You Clicked Update");
}

<div id="Key">Hi there</div>
<form name="DemoForm" action="">
    <button onclick="UpdateElapsed();return false;">Update</button>
</form>
```